# Libman VS Nuget Packages for client side libraries

Tags: package, blazor-webassembly, nuget-package, client-side, libman

What is the need for Library Manager(Libman), if we can install client-side libraries from NuGet packages directly?

I tried both but can't differentiate between them. Please point out the differences between libman and NuGet packages?

Answer (score 0):

[What Is Libman?](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/using-libman-to-manage-client-side-dependencies#what-is-libman)

> Short for Library Manager, **Libman is a lightweight tool designed explicitly for client-side library acquisition.** Client-side libraries are typically ready to be used by a client, and some examples include Bootstrap.js, JQuery, Vue, d3, and HTMX. Libman also supports some of the more popular CDNs that can host JavaScript libraries: CDNJS, jsDelivr, and unpkg. LibMan will retrieve specified libraries and place them in a target location. **The tool is for developers who work with final assets and don’t need a build pipeline.**

> To be clear, LibMan is not a package management system like Nuget, NPM or Yarn, and it doesn’t have the same facilities as WebPack, Rollup, or Parcel. As a result, it cannot replace those tools but offers folks a more straightforward choice.